# Не всегда происходит отправка письма

Tags: php, html, email

Есть send.php, в нем проблем вроде нет.

```
<?php
$msg = "<h3>Обратая связь</h3>";
if(isset($_POST['name'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['tel'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$_POST['tel'];}
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$_POST['phone'];}
if(isset($_POST['mail'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>E-mail:</strong> ".$_POST['mail'];}
if(isset($_POST['firstvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Экологический стандарт:</strong> ".$_POST['firstvalue'];}
if(isset($_POST['secondvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Что-то еще:</strong> ".$_POST['secondvalue'];}
if(isset($_POST['thirstvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Последний пункт:</strong> ".$_POST['thirstvalue'];}



$EOL = "\r\n";
$boundary     = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";
$headers   .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";
$headers   .= "From: asd@gmail.com";

$multipart  = "--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL;
$multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($msg));

$to  = 'asdf@gmail.com';

$subject = "Обратная связь";

mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers);

header('Location: https://moonway.by/aks?success=ok');
```

?>

И есть два модальных окна с формами, использующими этот скрипт отправки
В первом только одно поле - телефон. Отправка письма из этой формы работает.

```
<form class="under-construction" method="post" action="send.php">
   <div class="form-group email">
       <input class="form-control email" type="tel" name="tel"placeholder="Введите Ваш номер">
   </div>
   <button data-hover="Заказать звонок" class="btn btn-default btn-block progress-button" type="submit">
       <span class="button-label">Заказать звонок</span>
   </button>
 </form>
```

И вторая форма, не работает. Суть в том, что значения в input hidden подставляет js-скрипт.

```
<form class="under-construction" method="post" action="send.php">
                <div class="form-group email">
                    <input class="form-control name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required>
                    <input class="form-control tel" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш номер телефона" required>
                    <input class="form-control email" type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Введите Ваш e-mail">
                    <input type="hidden" name="firstvalue" id="firstvalue">
                    <input type="hidden" name="secondvalue" id="secondvalue">
                    <input type="hidden" name="thirstvalue" id="thirstvalue">
                </div>
                <button data-hover="Отправить" class="btn btn-default btn-block progress-button" type="submit">
                    <span class="button-label">Отправить</span>  
                </button>                       
            </form>
```

Пробовала из send.php удалять строки, отвечающие именно за эти скрытые инпуты, и письма отправлялись.
В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:** Перепробованы все возможные варианты. Письмо не приходит, если в форме есть поля, заполненные с помощью js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закинула сайт на WordPress, подключила Contact Form 7 - заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Пару способов для получения ошибки от php, которые должны дать понять в чем проблема и как с ней бороться.

```html
<?php
$msg = "<h3>Обратая связь</h3>";
if(isset($_POST['name'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['tel'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$_POST['tel'];}
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$_POST['phone'];}
if(isset($_POST['mail'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>E-mail:</strong> ".$_POST['mail'];}
if(isset($_POST['firstvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Экологический стандарт:</strong> ".$_POST['firstvalue'];}
if(isset($_POST['secondvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Что-то еще:</strong> ".$_POST['secondvalue'];}
if(isset($_POST['thirstvalue'])) { $msg .= "<br><strong>Последний пункт:</strong> ".$_POST['thirstvalue'];}

/* 
  Для начала можно проверить несколькими способами формирования 
  сообщения заполняя поля firstvalue, secondvalue, thirstvalue и 
  если php выдает строку а не ошибку при формировании тогда идем 
  ниже (не используя print_r($msg);)
*/
print_r($msg); exit;


$EOL = "\r\n";
$boundary     = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";
$headers   .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";
$headers   .= "From: asd@gmail.com";

$multipart  = "--$boundary$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8$EOL";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";
$multipart .= $EOL;
$multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($msg));

$to  = 'asdf@gmail.com';

$subject = "Обратная связь";

// Здесь мы вставляем проверку на отправку письма
$result = mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
if (!$result) {
    // и если произошла ошибка выводим сообщение
    print_r(error_get_last()['message']);
    exit;
}

header('Location: https://moonway.by/aks?success=ok');
```

Comment: Попробовала. Ошибки никакой нет. Выводится именно то, что и должно, но письма тоже нет.

Comment: Ок, 1-ый способ с `print_r()`, отпадает при отправке письма добавил `exit;`, попробуйте теперь, т.к. без выхода происходил редирект и не видно было ошибки.

Comment: Безрезультатно, происходит то же самое

Comment: Не понимаю как могут 3 поля изменить отправку письма, если вы их проверили выше ранее, т.е. строка формируется без ошибки. В следствии чего думаю проблема либо из-за отправки на gmail, который в некоторых случаях требует авторизации от отправителя (отправка через SMTP с указанием логина и пароля от исходящей почты), либо это всё происки РКН 8-). Больше предположений нет, может у кого-то другого будут мысли и он даст ответ.

Comment: Пробовала на mail.ru отправлять, не помогает.
Спасибо, буду тогда через smtp пытаться.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уверены что при клике на кнопку отправить во второй форме , происходит отправка формы?

Просто у вас там тег button не закрыт.

И зачем в тег button совать `<span class="button-label">Отправить</span>` , не проще тег button стилизовать?

Comment: Button закрыт, сюда не полностью скопировала. Span, да и в целом все стили - это издержки шаблона, к которому и нужно прикрутить отправку формы.
Отправка происходит, это факт. Если убираются те три hidden, все работает.